# PHP: Total Cost

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add all product prices together based off of quantity. The only issue is that each item is added at random, based on user selection, where they can be then adjusted to any random quantity.

Tried making an additional array to the store the variables to add them together, but it didn't take in the QT ammount.

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$total = 0;

// Fetch Database

$results->data_seek(0);

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item => $quantity) {

    $row = $results->fetch_assoc();

    $pId    = $row['ProductID'];
    $pName  = $row['ProductName'];
    $pImg   = $row['ProductImg'];
    $pPrice = $row['Price'];
    $pInfo  = $row['About'];

    foreach ($quantity as $quantity) {

        $priceA = array();

        $pushA = $pPrice * $quantity;

        array_push($priceA, $pushA);

        $bT = implode(",", $priceA);

        $total += $priceA;

    }

?>
```

**markup**

```
    <div class="col">
        <img src="img/<?php echo $pImg; ?>">

        <h1><?php
            echo $pName;
        ?></h1>

        <h2>$<?php
            echo $pPrice;
        ?></h2>

        <h3>QT: <?php echo $quantity; ?> 
          <a href="addc.php?id=<?php echo $pId ?>">+</a> 
          <a href="rc.php?id=<?php echo $pId ?>">-</a></h3>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <div class="cpan">
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="allc">
                <h1>Your total: <?php echo ($total); ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**php**

```
// Add 1 QT

$item = $_GET['id'];
$quantity = 1;

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$item])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item] += $quantity;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = $quantity;
}


// Remove 1 QT 

$item = $_GET['id'];
$quantity = 1;

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$item])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item] -= $quantity;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = $quantity;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you print out `$_SESSION['cart']`? `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);`

Comment: Yes, it is a multidimensional array set up like this;         $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = $quantity; Where you can add or subtract quantity with simple += or -=.

Comment: an example of the exact data wouldreally help

Comment: I added in an image to represent the data you asked for. ID => QT, ie PRODUCT ID = 4 => QT = 3 & so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

- Remove secondary foreach
- Change variables to match...

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    $total = 0;

    // Fetch Database

    $results->data_seek(0);

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item => $quantity) {

        $row = $results->fetch_assoc();

        $pId    = $row['ProductID'];
        $pName  = $row['ProductName'];
        $pImg   = $row['ProductImg'];
        $pPrice = $row['Price'];
        $pInfo  = $row['About'];


            $priceA = array();

            $pushA = $pPrice * $quantity;

            array_push($priceA, $pushA);

            $bT = implode(",", $priceA);

            $total += $bT; // Change to $bT

    ?>
```